# Como transformar um texto em nome de identificador?

Tags: python, string, eval

Eu gostaria de poder receber uma string como parâmetro e utilizar como nome de identificador, criar uma variável ou função com aquele nome (não serve usar como chave de dicionário). É possível fazer isso?

Comment: Qual seria a utilidade disso? Parece-me estranho, pois você, como desenvolvedor, não tem como saber qual será o nome da variável que o usuário digitará, então como irá utilizá-la no código?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível. Você precisa conhecer [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval), [`exec()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) e [`compile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile), mas não faça uma gambiarra dessas.

Sempre tem uma solução melhor a não ser que o que deseje é executar um código entrado externamente, o que não deixa de ser o recurso errado para isto, mas é uma forma de resolver, mesmo ainda sendo uma gambiarra.

Até o dicionário costuma ser gambiarra na maioria dos casos, embora já seria uma solução um pouco melhor e resolve a questão.