# Qual o uso do método .isidentifier() em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Me deparei com o método *string* `.isidentifier()` e também o `.isprintable()`.

- Por que usá-los?
- Em quais ocasiões eu usaria isso?

Comment: Agora, além de aceitar respostas das suas perguntas, você pode votar em todo o site também, em todas respostas ou perguntas que te agradar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Estes métodos são analisadores de um texto, eles varrem todo o texto e analisam se todos os caracteres, sem exceção, se encaixam em determinadas regras, ou seja, se todos estão dentro de uma faixa de caracteres que são válidos para um determinado uso.

O `isidentifier()` retornará `True` se todos os caracteres são válidos para escrever um identificador no código, então eles são letras maiúsculas e minúsculas, dígitos, desde que não seja o primeiro caractere e mais alguns caracteres Unicode. A lista completa do que é válido pode ser vista na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3.9/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers).

O uso deles é mais quando está construindo algum *parser* ou algum gerador de fórmulas, algo que depois precisará usar como identificador mesmo, talvez através de um [`eval()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/252107/101) (veja mais em [Como executar código arbitrário no Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138214/101) ou [Qual a diferença entre essas formas de execução de comando?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/302828/101)), ou seja, é raro ou mesmo não deve usar.

O `isprintable()` retornará `True` quando todos os caracteres são visíveis quando manda imprimi-los, isto incluindo os óbvios, mas também alguns menos óbvios como os que geram espaço em branco que não deixam de serem imprimíveis. Um exemplo de caractere não imprimível é o nulo (`\0`). Ele tem que ocupar espaço em tela ou papel.

O mais comum de usá-lo é saber que se ele contará para determinar o espaço ocupado em uma impressão qualquer em qualquer suporte ou se poderá causar algum erro por que criar uma situação inesperada, por exemplo um `\8` que é um *backspace*, então ele pode retroceder um caractere, então em vez de ocupar mais um caractere ele ocupa menos, apagando o anterior.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Conceptual.md).